# conexion a sql desde c#

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema, mi pc nueva trae windows 10 home, por temas de garantia no he querido actualizarla a windows 10 pro.

Instalé correctamente SQL SERVER 2017, pero al iniciar el SQL MANAGMENT presenta un error de la conexión, activé el servidor y las características en el mmc y sigue igual, después de varios intentos de ingresar por fin me lo permite, estoy desarrollando algo básico en C#, realicé la conexión a la base de datos normalmente, probé conexión y es correcta pero al ejecutar  me dice que hay problemas de conexión de red. estoy probando con algo básico para colocar todo en orden.
¿Qué puede ser?
me muestra un código de error

> 0x80070000

Comment: Deja el código de lo que estas intentando en C#, sino es imposible ayudarte;